# foreach return object property javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following code, can somebody explain why object property is returned using a for loop but not using a forEach.
Is it something related to returning object references or is it something specific to forEach loop on an array ?

```
var empModule = (function(){
    var empArray = [{
        "name":"Aish",
        "age":"27",
        "location": "All"
    },{
        "name":"Anu",
        "age":"26",
        "location": "Muz"
    },{
        "name":"Vern",
        "age":"25",
        "location": "Mang"
    }];

    var searchAge = function(name){  
        for(var i=0;i<empArray.length;i++) {
            if(empArray[i].name === name) {
                return empArray[i].age;
            }
        };
    };

    var searchLocation = function(name){
        empArray.forEach(function(obj){
            if(name === obj.name) {
                return obj.location;
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        findAge: searchAge,
        findLocation: searchLocation
    };

})();
var secAge = empModule.findAge("Anu");
console.log(secAge); // Correct Output
var thirdLoc = empModule.findLocation("Vern");
console.log(thirdLoc); // Returns undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` returns to the function it's in. In the `for..` example, that's `searchAge`. When you use `forEach()`, you pass it a callback function, and so you return the value to that callback. You never return anything in `searchLocation`.

You should just use the regular `for..` loop both times here.

Answer (score 2):

in java script there is no break method for `forEach`.

if you use

```
return obj.location
```

it has no effect on it

but when you use return method in for loop then that will break and return the value.

There is [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which has a break method.

`Some` break on `return true` and `every` break on `return false;`

try like this

```
var location = "";
empArray.some(function (obj) {
    if (name === obj.name) {
        location = obj.location;
        return true;
    }
});
return location;
```

Or try like this

```
var location = "";
empArray.every(function (obj) {
    if (name === obj.name) {
        location = obj.location;
        return false;
    }
});.
return location;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because in the bellow code snippet

```
var searchLocation = function(name){
    empArray.forEach(function(obj){
        if(name === obj.name) {
            return obj.location;
        }
    });
};
```

If you want to do the same thing use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) like bellow

```
var searchLocation = function(name){
   return empArray.filter(function(obj) {
      return name === obj.name
   })[0].location;
};
```

the `return` statement will be for `anonymous function` you are giving as parameter to `foreach` function not to function `searchLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
>   unlike every() and some(), it always returns the value undefined.

So you could try this which sets a variable and returns it after the loop:

```
 var searchLocation = function(name){
    var result;
    empArray.forEach(function(obj){
        if(name === obj.name) {
            result =  obj.location;
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```